# How to change a subview using the YUI App framework

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, view, yui

I'm creating an app using the YUI App framework for the first time. So I'm still trying to understand how it all works.

My app will be showing several views at the same time, this is done by using nested views. When navigating the app it should be possible to change only one of the (sub)views without having to re-render the parentview.

I have created a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/casperskovgaard/BDqjz/6/

The app will render a HomePageView containing two subviews. A menu view and a content view. From the menu view it is possible to change the content view.

Code that renders the homepage looks like this:

```
render: function () {
    Y.log('render homepage view');
    var container = this.get('container');

    container.setHTML(this.template());
    container.one('#menu').setHTML(new Y.MenuView().render().get('container'));
    container.one('#content').setHTML(this.get('content').render().get('container'));

    return this;
}
```

The content view will change if the route is changed.

As it is now HomePageView and both subview will re-render every time the route is changed.

How can I change it, so only the content view is re-rendered, when clicking the links in the menu view?

Also I'm a bit confused on how to use the container attribute on the subviews, any tips will be appreciated

-Casper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on further description in comment under first answer, I would still remove the MenuView and other subviews from the "views" property as it is really only used for views that will be made the "activeView" which they won't.

I would make the HomePageView a "preserved" view and use the "callback" property to the options object passed to 'showView' to tell that view what content to be shown.

So 'views' now looks like:

```
views: {
    homePage: {type: 'HomePageView', preserve: true}
}
```

And your handler(s) looks like:

```
handleFirst: function () {
    this.showView(
        'homePage',
        null,
        { 
            callback: function (view) { 
                view.showContent(Y.FirstView); 
            }
        }
    );
}
```

And I added a method to HomePageView like so:

```
showContent: function (ctr) {
    Y.log("HomePageView::showContent: " + ctr);
    var container = this.get('container');

    container.one('#content').setHTML((new ctr).render().get('container'));
}
```

That's the simplest case where it takes the constructor of the view to put into the content area and re-creates it each time, etc. There is no reason why the instance of HomePageView can't keep a cache of its subviews and only create them when needed, etc. Either way the key is that you can use a callback to manipulate the underlying view when it becomes the "activeView" at the top level. (Alternatively I've done this such that I fire an event on that view rather than passing something to it and then use an event handler on the view to do the dirty work, but I don't know how comfortable you are with custom events.)

http://jsfiddle.net/brianjmiller/eP7s2/2/

Hopefully take two works.

Comment: If you need true subview history maintenance then you might stop by #yui on IRC and ask @hatch about his pending gallery module. AFAIK, there isn't an easy way to do it via core App features at the moment. Y.App pretty much expects a single top "active" view. I've done something slightly different using a "controller" type module sitting one level up and having the app instance fire events that bubble up and control other parts of the page.

Comment: Well, this seems to be what I'm looking for. My only concern right now is the code isn't very elegant, because the showView method will always call the same view (homepage). So the idea of changing the view from the app is moved to the view. But I think you are right that App expects a single active view. You alternative idea about using custom events on the homepage view is interesting. I'll play around a bit more, and come back with more feedback later. Big thanks for the help so far :-)

Answer (score 1):

The key here is if you always want the menu displayed for the page and only change the content view based on route handlers then you should set the "viewContainer" node in the Y.App configuration to the #content DOM node. Along with that rather than having your route handlers .showView on the homePage they should show the view directly associated with their route. So .handleFirst would show "firstView". To achieve this I would remove "homePage" and "menuView" from the "views" property in the app and have them handled at a higher level, that way they only happen once, and you'll have already rendered the viewContainer node into the DOM before instantiating your Y.App instance.

In effect you have two stages,

1) Page/app loading: so initial setup happens once, create the page via your HomePage view and then create your App and hook the two together,

2) Content loading: your app instance handles all of this via routing and only affects the content "pane".

```
var mymainview = new Y.HomePageView().render();
Y.one("body").append(mymainview.get("container"));

var myapp = new Y.MyApp({
    transitions: true,
    viewContainer: "#content"
});

myapp.render();
```

Sample edits to your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/brianjmiller/W74uc/1/

See http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/app/#rendering-an-app for info on viewContainer.

(For your subview query you should open a separate more specific question.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Brian, but this isn't exactly what I need. The menu view isn't static. I need several views on the page at the same time and be able to render only one of them. In the example you provided there is only one active view on the page.